# Connection to database failure

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I can't seem to figure out the problem with my database or the connection to it. I get this error when I try to run it.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php on line 54

AND

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php:53 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/scripts/registerUser.php(41): MySQLDAO->registerUser('email', 'aske', 'meyer', '1bf528e7f15d11c...', 'KO\x8E\xD0\xCE/\xBD\xACK\xD1d\x18\x9A\x07\xE1...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php on line 53

Connection file:

```
<?php class Conn { public static $dbhost = "localhost";
        public static $dbuser = "root";
        public static $dbpass = "";
        public static $dbname = "app";} ?>
```

MySQL file:

```
public function registerUser($email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt)
{ 
    $sql = "insert into users set email=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, user_password=?, salt=?";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement)
      throw new Exception($statement->error);
    $statement->bind_param("sssss", $email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt);
    $returnValue = $statement->execute();
    return $returnValue;  
}
```

This is line 54. `if (!$statement) throw new Exception($statement->error);`

Comment: `$statement->error` should be `$this->conn->error`.

Comment: `insert into users set email=?,...`? You're confused between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operation.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the quick answer, though i now get this        Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Table 'app.users' doesn't exist' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php:54 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/scripts/registerUser.php(41): MySQLDAO->registerUser('email', 'aske', 'meyer', '0ebfe15868c034d...', '\x8FM:\x87\x135j\xC8\xA7\xD7:mH\x88\xF8...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php on line 54

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear. There's no table named `users` in the `app` database.

Answer (score 0):

The `if()` block runs when `$statement = FALSE`, so `$statement->error` can't possibly be right. The `error` property is in `$this->conn`, so it should be

```
if (!$statement) {
    throw new Exception($this->conn->error);
}
```

Then the error message will show the problem with your SQL.

Comment: hey @Barmar i now get this Fatal error: that i miss app.users                                                                                         i have in my database setup as followed - userID - email - first_name - last_name - user_password - salt & binary.. i cant see why or where i should implement users ?

Comment: Use a `CREATE TABLE` query to create the table. Or use a tool like PhpMyAdmin to manage your database.